# How do I check which apps are hibernated the most by Greenify (so that if I don't use them, I can freeze them)?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, greenify

I'm on a rooted LG G3 and running Android 5.0 - I have the paid versions of Greenify and Titanium Backup on my phone.

I just want to know if there's a way to check which apps are hibernated most often by Greenify so that, if I decide that there are often-hibernated apps that I don't really use that much, I can opt instead to freeze them using Titanium Backup.

Comment: I'm bit confused here. 1) Is the phone under consideration really yours? 2) If it is your phone, then wouldn't you know by yourself which apps *you don't really use that much*? 3) Did you hibernate some system apps/components as well which you can't tell whether you're using them or not?

Comment: 1) Yes it's mine 2) I know which apps I don't really use that much, but I don't know what apps Greenify hibernates the most (because a lot of apps/services could be triggering constantly in the background and Greenify hibernates them often, but I don't monitor these so I don't know) 3) I don't know what you're asking here... sorry.